# IHTMLElement::getAttribute return not all

Tags: c++, com

I have link tag(a _href=''). Attribute "_href" have 5473 symbols. I try get it, but returned only 5120 symbols. How can I fix it ?

```
IHTMLElement *pSelectElement;

_variant_t var;
pSelectElement->getAttribute(L"_href", 2, &var);
```

Comment: Is the attribute called "_href" or "href", your question says one thing, but your code says something else.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. You need to include at least, all the code and the XML file you are trying to read. It would be best if you try and reproduce the problem with a smaller XML file and with as little code as you can.

Comment: To be honest, 5120 WCHARs (=10240 bytes) sounds like a built-in limitation.

Comment: Xml is correct. Attribute data is repeated. All work fine in small attribute. But large attribute doesn't work fine.